# Does diesel requires mysql and sqlite to be installed?

Tags: database, rust, rust-diesel

I'm doing `RUN cargo install diesel_cli` in my docker image, and I get:

= note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

only `postgres` is installed.

Do I really need to install sqlite3 and mysqlclient even though I'm not going to use then? I want to keep my container small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `[dependencies]` as for Postgres only:

```
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.6", features = ["postgres"] }
```

Note you have to specify `features` and explicitly remove `mysql` and `sqlite` which are present by default.

For a `cargo install` the same principle should apply but you need to add `--no-default-features` to turn off defaults:

```sh
cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

Comment: But this is not in a cargo project, I'm just using cargo to install diesel, there are no depdenencies

Comment: I've added a version for the command-line approach, didn't see that in your question. As `diesel_cli` has `diesel` as a dependency you may need to pass it features too, I'd have to check.

Comment: `RUN cargo install diesel_cli --features postgres` still gives errors about linking with `mysql` and `sqlite`

Comment: That's because it's actually `diesel` which does that, which is why I wondered if installing that first with the requisite features helps satisfy it later.